# Azure Function - SharePoint CSOM call with currently signed in user

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, azure-functions

I have a azure function and making a CSOM call to SharePoint online. The authentication was done with App ClientId & ClientSecret. Everything working fine. I am capturing a DocSet version via CSOM call (its available only with CSOM) and CreatedBY is showing as "SharePoint App". I would like to make this azure call to run with currently signed in user.. i.e. CreatedBy should show current user's name. Kindly help.

```
    public static class CaptureDocSetVersion
  {
    [FunctionName("CaptureDocSetVersion")]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]
    HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
      log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

      // parse query parameter
      var qs = req.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();

      string itemId = qs.Get("id");

      if (itemId == null)
      {
        // Get request body
        dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
        itemId = data?.itemId;
      }
      if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(itemId))
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Please pass a item id on the query string or in the request body");
      
      try
      {
        log.Info("Item id:" + itemId);
        string result = CaptureDocSetVersion.CaptureVersion(itemId);
        log.Info(result);
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Version captured for item " + itemId);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        log.Info("Error occured :" + ex.ToString());
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Error ocurred while capturing the docset version");
      }
    }

    private static ClientContext GetonlineContext()
    {
      string ServiceSiteUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContractSiteUrl"];
      var clientID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"];
      var clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientSecret"];
      //ideally this should be done with SSO once identity provider issue is fixed
      var authManager = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();
      ClientContext clientContext = authManager.GetAppOnlyAuthenticatedContext(ServiceSiteUrl, clientID, clientSecret);
      return clientContext;      
    }

    public static string CaptureVersion(string itemId)
    {
      var listId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContractFormListId"];
      var ctx = GetonlineContext();
      ctx.Load(ctx.Web);
      var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetById(new Guid(listId));
      var item = list.GetItemById(itemId);
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      var folder = item.Folder;
      ctx.Load(folder);
      var ds = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentSet.DocumentSet.GetDocumentSet(ctx, folder);
      ctx.Load(ds);
      var dsVersions = ds.VersionCollection;
      dsVersions.Add(true, "Captured through azure function app");
      ctx.ExecuteQuery();
      return "CSOM code executed";
    }
  }
```

SPFx call here

```
public captureVersion = async (id: number): Promise<any> => {
        let azADClient: AadHttpClient = await this.context.aadHttpClientFactory
            .getClient('a7a4b1df-b30c-44fa-b0be-9dd2ab9647ab');
        let url = `${constants.CAPTUREDOCSETVERSION_AZFUNC_URL}&id=${id}`;
        const requestHeaders: Headers = new Headers();
        requestHeaders.append('Content-type', 'application/json');

        const httpClientOptions: IHttpClientOptions = {
            headers: requestHeaders
        };

        try {
            let response: HttpClientResponse = await (azADClient.get(
                url, AadHttpClient.configurations.v1, httpClientOptions));
            // let response: HttpClientResponse = await (this.context.httpClient.get(
            //     url, HttpClient.configurations.v1, httpClientOptions));
            let json = await response.json();
            return json;
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
```

Here is the Azure Identity provider information

SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal

API Permissions

User.Read and user_impersonation

Whenever I am making SPFx call I am gettin HTTP status 500 and azure function was never hit.. Also, the Azure function app is going into "Azure functions runtime is unreachable state" and I am forced to delete and recreate the Azure Function App again.

Comment: What are you using to trigger the Azure function? A button inside an SPFx solution? or something else?

Comment: Yes.. A button inside a SPFx form. It is to capture DocSet version and its available only with CSOM.. (Not in PnPJS or REST API).. [link] https://www.nivas.org/Using-SharePoint-Online-CSOM-to-Capture-Versions-of-Document-Sets

Answer (score 0):

If you following this article, then you'll be able to call SharePoint API from an Azure function using currently logged in user in an SFPx webpart/extension: [Consume enterprise APIs secured with Azure AD in SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient-enterpriseapi)

> This article illustrates how you would connect to an enterprise API
> secured with Azure Active Directory from a SharePoint Framework
> solution. It covers both creating and securing the API as well as
> building the SharePoint Framework solution.

Comment: I've made several unfruitful attempts.. I've added all the code the above.. am I missing anything? Appreciate if you could help.